# undefined is not a function evaluating _this2.props.navigator.push

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to scaffold a simple drawer and navigation in react-native.

As you can see I import the drawer and then I instantiate the Navigator below the Toolbar.

I want to be able to change the route from the AppDrawer but the only thing I get after the button click is

***undefined is not a function (evaluating '_this2.props.navigator.push({ id: 'component5' })') ***

*Note: I have not attached Component 3 or 5 code because they are simple text renders.*

> index.android.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Text, View, Navigator, ToolbarAndroid} from 'react-native';

import Component3 from "./app/components/Component3/Component3";
import Component5 from "./app/components/Component5/Component5";


import MyAppDrawer from "./app/components/Miscellaneous/AppDrawer";
import Drawer from 'react-native-drawer';


const drawerStyles = {
    drawer: {
        shadowColor: "#343477",
        shadowOpacity: 0.8,
        shadowRadius: 0,
    }
}


export default class ReactTest extends Component {

    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.state = {
            drawerType: 'overlay',
            openDrawerOffset: 50,
            closedDrawerOffset: 0,
            panOpenMask: .1,
            panCloseMask: .9,
            relativeDrag: false,
            panThreshold: .25,
            tweenHandlerOn: false,
            tweenDuration: 350,
            tweenEasing: 'linear',
            disabled: false,
            tweenHandlerPreset: null,
            acceptDoubleTap: false,
            acceptTap: false,
            acceptPan: true,
            tapToClose: false,
            negotiatePan: false,
            rightSide: false,
        };
    }


    openDrawer() {
        this.drawer.open()
    }


    renderScene(route, navigator) {
        switch (route.id) {
            case 'component2':
                return (<Component2 navigator={navigator}/>)
            case 'component3':
                return (<Component3 navigator={navigator}/>)
            case 'component4':
                return (<Component4 navigator={navigator}/>)
            case 'component5':
                return (<Component5 navigator={navigator} title="component5"/>)
            case 'component6':
                return (<Component6 user={route.user} navigator={navigator} title="component6"/>)
        }
    }

    onActionSelected(position) {
        console.log("Settings clicked");
    }

    onIconClicked(position) {
        console.log("App Drawer clicked");
    }


    render() {
        var controlPanel = <MyAppDrawer navigator={navigator} closeDrawer={() => {
            this.drawer.close();
        }}/>
        return (


            <View style={styles.containerToolbar}>


                <Drawer
                    ref={c => this.drawer = c}
                    type={this.state.drawerType}
                    animation={this.state.animation}
                    captureGestures={true}
                    openDrawerOffset={this.state.openDrawerOffset}
                    closedDrawerOffset={this.state.closedDrawerOffset}
                    panOpenMask={this.state.panOpenMask}
                    //panCloseMask={this.state.panCloseMask}
                    relativeDrag={this.state.relativeDrag}
                    panThreshold={this.state.panThreshold}
                    content={controlPanel}
                    styles={drawerStyles}
                    disabled={this.state.disabled}
                    // tweenHandler={this.tweenHandler.bind(this)}
                    // tweenDuration={this.state.tweenDuration}
                    // tweenEasing={this.state.tweenEasing}
                    acceptDoubleTap={this.state.acceptDoubleTap}
                    acceptTap={this.state.acceptTap}
                    acceptPan={this.state.acceptPan}
                    tapToClose={this.state.tapToClose}
                    negotiatePan={this.state.negotiatePan}
                    // changeVal={this.state.changeVal}
                    side={this.state.rightSide ? 'right' : 'left'}
                >
                    <ToolbarAndroid
                        style={styles.toolbar}
                        title="MyApp"
                        // logo={require('./dummy_logo.png')}
                        navIcon={require("./navigation_icon.png")}
                        onActionSelected={this.onActionSelected}
                        onIconClicked={this.openDrawer.bind(this)}
                        titleColor="black"
                        actions={[
                            {title: "Log out", show: "never"}
                        ]}
                    />
                    <Navigator
                        style={styles.container}
                        initialRoute={{id: 'component3'}}
                        renderScene={this.renderScene}/>
                </Drawer>

            </View>
        );
    }


}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    containerToolbar: {
        flex: 1,
        //justifyContent: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
        // https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2957#event-417214498
        alignItems: 'stretch',
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    },
    toolbar: {
        backgroundColor: '#e9eaed',
        height: 56,
    },

});


AppRegistry.registerComponent('ReactTest', () => ReactTest);
```

> AppDrawer.js

import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import {View, Text, Button, Navigator} from 'react-native';

```
import styles from './styles';

export default class AppDrawer extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.controlPanel}>
                <Text style={styles.controlPanelWelcome}>
                    Control Panel
                </Text>
                <Button
                    onPress={() => {
                        console.log("pressed");
                        this.props.navigator.push({
                            id: 'component5',
                        });
                    }}  
                    title="Component 5"
                />
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have `MyAppDrawer` inside your renderScene function, you don't have access to the navigator. You would need to add a ref and use that to get the navigator:

Add `ref={navigator => this.navigator = navigator}` to your Navigator component, then you can do

```
<MyAppDrawer navigator={this.navigator} closeDrawer={() => {
    this.drawer.close();
}}/>
```

Comment: also, it might be a good idea to take your control panel outside of your render and turn it into a function that returns a component.

Comment: Very good point indeed. 
Added :
        ref={navigator => this.navigator = navigator}
Modified:
      <MyAppDrawer navigator={this.navigator} closeDrawer={() => {  this.drawer.close(); }}/>
But i am still getting the same error.

Comment: What React Native version are you using? If its RN 0.44, Navigator was deprecated.

Comment: I am using RN 0.43. Ater many tries I still get the error. I will try implementing routing via React Navigation. Thank you so much for your input.